# How to use other camera depth buffer to render the scene on another camera in URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I have two camera in the same position. I want to use the first camera's depth buffer to render the scene again on the second camera.

Use case:
I want to detect if a line that I draw on the 3d space is rendered behind an object or not. To do that, first I draw the scene normally on the first camera. Then I render the scene again on the second camera, which rendered unto a texture and set to culled all object except the line. The line is using a shader that will shows Red on the part that rendered behind an object, but to draw it correctly I need to render the second camera using the first camera's depth buffer. After that I just check if the texture has the red color.

Is it possible to do that on URP? Or do you guys have any other idea how to achieve what I want? [!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hxDo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hxDo.png)